# How to get part of string that matches with regular expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, regex

I am having a requirement where I need to parse a column value to get a work request number associated with it. For example, the column value may contain - **"Worked on AB-0012589"** or **"AB-0012589 is completed"** or whatever containing the work request number in it. (*Here **AB-0012589** is the work request number*).

Format of the work request number will not change. It will be in **xx-xxxxxxx** format, where two characters before the hyphen will be *letters* and the later part will be *numbers*. How can I parse the work request number from the column value using regular expression?

So, if the column value is "**Completed AC-0015587**" my desired output is **AC-0015587**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From the column value, I want to get the part which matches the XX-XXXXXXX pattern. As said in the example given in my question.

Comment: check out my edited answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40740839/3884240)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Create function ReturnPart (@val as varchar(100))
 Returns varchar(10)
 as
 begin
 declare @length as int 
 declare @loop as int
 declare @ret as varchar(10)
 set @loop =1
 set @length = len(@val)

 while @loop<=@length-9
    begin
    if exists(select 1 where substring(@val,@loop,10) like '[a-z][a-z][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
        set @ret = substring(@val,@loop,10)
    set @loop=@loop+1
    end
Return @ret
end



select dbo.ReturnPart('Worked on AB-0012589')
select dbo.ReturnPart('AB-0012589 is completed')
```

Comment: Works Great! Thanks @cloudsafe and congratulations on your early points :)

Answer (score 7):

This works:

```
declare @Value nvarchar(4000)
set @Value='Worked a-232 on AB-0012589'

select substring(@Value,
patindex('%[A-Z][A-Z][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@Value),10)
```

Replace @Value with your column

Output:
*AB-0012589*

Comment: just replace `Value` with your column and `(select  'Worked on AB-0012589'  as Value) as MyTable`  with your table name

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it will not work if there is any other hyphen in the column value. Is there any way that I can match the exact XX-XXXXXXX format?

Comment: Thanks a lot Nina!

Comment: fixed it. replace `len(@Value)` with 10

Answer (score 1):

```
 select substring('Completed AC-0015587',(CHARINDEX('-','Completed AC-0015587')-2), 10)
```

ouput
    AC-0015587

Comment: The work request will not be the same every time. It may change, but the format will be the same. That is why I am looking for a regular expression solution.

Comment: yes it will work u can check by using column name only for this format
xx-xxxxxxx ..@Subha

Comment: I do not want to separate out letters and numbers from here. My question is, if I have a column which has a value like "Worked on AV-0217585" how can I parse and get the value "AV-0217585" from there? See I can't hard code the number. That is going to change. The format will be the same. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: canu check now this is what u are expecting ..@Subha

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I am expecting something like this, but it will not work if there is any other hyphen in the column value. Is there any way that I can match the exact XX-XXXXXXX format?

Comment: please post one example so that we can check that one too @Subha

Answer (score 1):

You can try using below expression

`substring(t1.column_value,(CHARINDEX('-',t1.column_value)-2), 10)`

Using above gave me below result

[image]

Hope this should help you out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it will not work if there is any other hyphen in the column value. Is there any way that I can match the exact XX-XXXXXXX format?

Answer (score 1):

Use patindex and find '-' position from that we can fetch work request number

```
select substring('Completed AC-0015587',
          patindex('%-%','Completed AC-0015587')-2,len('Completed AC-0015587'))
```

Update: Change patindex like below it may help you

```
select substring('Worked on- AV-0217585',
patindex('%-[0-9]%','Worked on- AV-0217585')-2,len('Worked on- AV-0217585'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it will not work if there is any other hyphen in the column value. Is there any way that I can match the exact XX-XXXXXXX format?

Comment: @Subha Updated post check now.