# How to extract a string from the middle of an existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar column which could contain the following string example in the middle of the string

```
Cost Centre: 12345
```

or

```
Cost Code: 12345
```

The `12345` value could be dynamic, but it will always be a length of 5 digits.  Is there a way to extract the 5 digit number and output it as its own column?

Thank you for reading

George

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get part of string that matches with regular expression in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740419/how-to-get-part-of-string-that-matches-with-regular-expression-in-sql-server)

Comment: Combine [substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) with [patindex](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: A more representative example would be useful - your current examples imply end of string rather than middle of string

Comment: Fixing your design seems to be the solution in the end. Clearly Cost Centre and Cost Code should be separate columns with the details in there.

Comment: Yeah I agree. Normalise your DB first. E.g. Cost Code and Cost Centre should be column names in a table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `substring()`:

```
select t.*,
       substring(value, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', value), 5)
from t;
```

This returns the first 5-digit sequence in the string, which allows a lot of flexibility in malformed strings.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2e406e03917ac2863f39385854b61c0) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use STRING_SPLIT and then use LEFT to get the 5 characters. As there could be space, we need to apply TRIM, before LEFT function.

```sql
DECLARE @t table(charval VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO @t (charval)
VALUES ('Cost Centre: 12345'),
('Cost Code: 12345')


SELECT charval,LEFT(trim(value),5) as Just5Digits
from @t as t
CROSS APPLY string_split(t.charval,':')
WHERE value not like 'cost%'
```

```
+--------------------+--------------+
|      charval       | Just5Digits  |
+--------------------+--------------+
| Cost Centre: 12345 |        12345 |
| Cost Code: 12345   |        12345 |
+--------------------+--------------+
```